# WP_Query complexa

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, query

Estou montando uma agenda de eventos no Wordpress e preciso listar todos os eventos da semana agrupados pelo dia corrente. Tenho eventos que duram um dia apenas e outros que duram o mês inteiro. Criei o custom post type "Eventos" e os custom fields "data_inicio" e "data_fim". Como ficaria a query que me retorna os custom post types "eventos" de um dia mas também os que estão em andamento?

Answer (score 1):

Será que um loop normal resolveria?

```
$eventos = array( 'post_type' => 'eventos', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'meta_key' => 'data_inicio', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'DESC' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $eventos );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   the_title();
   the_content();
endwhile;
```

O loop acima mostraria os eventos publicados se utilizado dentro de uma archive-eventos.php que é basicamente um archive.php porém exlusivo do seu post type eventos ou uma page.php qualquer podendo ser page-eventos.php

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value

Não sou expert em WordPress mas creio que seria algo nesse tipo.

Comment: Vou testar. Obrigado.

Comment: Ainda não. :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você poderia fazer uma query buscando todos os eventos que futuros e que estejam acontecendo.

```
/**
* Agenda de eventos
*/
$today = date('Y-m-d');

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post_talk', // seu post type
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'       => 'data_inicio', // ordena os eventos por data de inicio
    'meta_type'      => 'DATE',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'ASC',

    // busca todos os eventos que a data de termino seja maior ou igual a hoje
    'meta_query'     => array(
         array(
            'key'     => 'data_fim',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value'   => $today,
            'type'    => 'DATE'
        )
    ),
);

$talks = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Para trazer apenas eventos da semana você pode combinar mais uma meta_query:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'data_fim',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value'   => $today,
        'type'    => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'data_inicio',
        'compare' => '<=',
        'value'   => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week')), // +7 dias
        'type'    => 'DATE'
    )
),
```